# Sorting a ListBox ListItems with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sort the items in a ListBox. However, upon doing so the Item Value gets set to the Item Text. Any help would be appreciated.

```
lbxCustomers.DataSource = lbxCustomers.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Reverse().ToList();
lbxCustomers.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you do something like this client side?

Comment: Because I'm partly using this project to benefit myself. (Getting a better understanding, and practice using, LINQ.) Otherwise, yeah, JQuery all the way.

Comment: Something else is going on here if the values are switching places. Are you saying that if you simply set the datasource to the `lbxCustomers.Items` collection, without any transforms, it works correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be first you should store the list in generic collection and then sort it. Something like this:

```
List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>(lbxCustomers.Items.Cast<ListItem>());
list = list.OrderBy(li => li.Text).ToList<ListItem>();
lbxCustomers.Items.Clear();
lbxCustomers.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray<ListItem>());
```

Comment: This worked great. Just had to use .OrderByDescending instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the Listbox after setting the DataSource. A lot of times if a control is already bound and you set the DataSource again, then it drops the DisplayMember/ValueMember properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the list separately.
Point the Text value and Data value in the next step.
Databind the control.