# Sorting items in a list box by button C#

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I have a list box on a Windows form in Visual Studio 2010 and would like the user to click a button and have the items in the list box sorted. E.g Alphabetical Order, Numerical Order.

I am new to C# and aren't sure where to start with writing the code for the sort button. I would very much appreciate if you could provide me with a starting point how to go about doing this.

This is the data for the list box when data is being added to it:

```
public Sale GetItemData()
{
    Sale newItem = new Sale(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), StartingDate.Text, ClosingDate.Text, txtLocation.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtDisplaySpaces.Text), txtExclusive.Text, txtME.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtDisplayStands.Text));
    return newItem;
}
```

This is the sort by ID button that I wish to use to sort the list box:

```
private void btnSortSalesbyID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: ... and you want us to write it?

Comment: I don't see any question..

Comment: Try search a little more next time... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690720/sorting-a-listbox-listitems-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

Take the items from the ListBoxand store them in a List then sort the List and put it back into the ListBox

Comment: I think this is better suited as a comment. If choosing to supply a full answer, add some code.

Answer (score 0):

See Chris Valentine's answer here: [Sorting a list of items in a list box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667088/sorting-a-list-of-items-in-a-list-box)

You will probably have to write a custom `Sort()` routine.